# "Le vélo de Tati” - Jacques Tati by Robert Doisneau

Tags: accessories

Does anyone know where i can purchase this iconic poster? I've searched the most obvious websites.

thanks

Comment: Best I could find was a postcard-sized reproduction on ebay.

Comment: http://www.art.co.uk/products/p14433152-sa-i2909596/robert-doisneau-le-velo-de-tati-c-1949.htm says "No longer available", but does at least mean that someone sold one sometime.

http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/lot/robert-doisneau-le-velo-de-tati-1949-4232651-details.aspx?intObjectID=4232651 is a 2004 sale of a print for $2,629

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad answer, but its been six months and noone else has a better one.

For personal use only AND given there appears to be no other way, you could either

1)  recreate it for yourself and take your own photograph,

2)  Scale this one as big as you reasonably can and then manually retouch it.     https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c5/2a/42/c52a428f7765eaaaa7ccbc1151b2f4f5.jpg

Both would probably be derivative works, and as long as you're not claiming it as your own original work, then there's little chance of someone accusing you of stealing the image.

Remember to give credit to the original artist.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Criggie for bringing this back to the front of the queue.

A quick [Google for "Le vélo de Tati”](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22Le+v%C3%A9lo+de+Tati%E2%80%9D&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCYQsARqFQoTCIuVq5Le7sgCFYS2Hgod29IFtQ&biw=1279&bih=729) shows that the largest online source is 1,722px × 2,048px (the first hit).

This is accessible at http://www.dreweatts.com/media/dreweatts/inventory/4/5/6/456745-8.jpg

As Criggie has already cautioned, be careful of copyright issues.

According to [Cristies](http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/photographs/robert-doisneau-jacques-tati-late-1950s-5374533-details.aspx), the original was 9½ x 7in. (24.3 x 18cm.), so the resolution found would print OK. A poster print of double the linear dimensions should look OK also.

The original doesn't look very sharp, so don't expect too much.

Comment: Your google-fu is stronger than mine - I missed that one.